# MutationObserver is reading old React State

Tags: reactjs, mutation-observers

I'm attempting to use a MutationObserver with the Zoom Web SDK to watch for changes in who the active speaker is. I declare a state variable using useState called `participants` which is meant to hold the information about each participant in the Zoom call.

My MutationObserver only seems to be reading the initial value of participants, leading me to believe the variable is bound/evaluated rather than read dynamically. Is there a way to use MutationObserver with React useState such that the MutationCallback reads state that is dynamically updating?

```
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState({});

  ...

  const onSpeechMutation = (mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
      // identify name of speaker
      if(name in participants) {
        // do something
      } else {
        setParticipants({
        ...participants,
        [name] : initializeParticipant(name)
        })
      }
    })
  }

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!speechObserverOn) {
      setSpeechObserverOn(true);
      const speechObserver = new MutationObserver(onSpeechMutation);
      const speechConfig = {
        attributes: true,
        attributeOldValue: true,
        attributeFilter: ['class'],
        subtree: true,
      }
      const participantsList = document.querySelector('.participants-selector');
      if(participantsList) {
        speechObserver.observe(participantsList, speechConfig);
      }
    }
  }, [speechObserverOn])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are dealing with stale state enclosures in callbacks then generally the solution is to use functional state updates so you are updating from the previous state and not what is closed over in any callback scope.

```
const onSpeechMutation = (mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    // identify name of speaker
    if (name in participants) {
      // do something
    } else {
      setParticipants(participants => ({
        ...participants, // <-- copy previous state
       [name]: initializeParticipant(name)
      }));
    }
  })
};
```

Also, ensure to include a dependency array for the `useEffect` hook unless you ***really*** want the effect to trigger upon each and every render cycle. I am guessing you don't want more than one `MutationObserver` at-a-time.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!speechObserverOn) {
    setSpeechObserverOn(true);
    const speechObserver = new MutationObserver(onSpeechMutation);
    const speechConfig = {
      attributes: true,
      attributeOldValue: true,
      attributeFilter: ['class'],
      subtree: true,
    }
    const participantsList = document.querySelector('.participants-selector');
    if(participantsList) {
      speechObserver.observe(participantsList, speechConfig);
    }
  }
}, []); // <-- empty dependency array to run once on component mount
```

### Update

> The issue is that `if (name in participants)` always returns false
> because participants is stale

For this a good trick is to use a React ref to cache a copy of the current state value so any callbacks can access the state value via the ref.

Example:

```
const [participants, setParticipants] = useState([.....]);
const participantsRef = useRef(participants);

useEffect(() => {
  participantsRef.current = participants;
}, [participants]);

...

const onSpeechMutation = (mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    // identify name of speaker
    if (name in participantsRef.current) {
      // do something
    } else {
      setParticipants(participants => ({
        ...participants,
       [name]: initializeParticipant(name)
      }));
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: The issue is that `if(name in participants)` always returns false because participants is stale -- participants seems to update correctly (I'm printing it out every few seconds, and a new participant has been added) but the if statement in the callback doesn't realize that. Thoughts?

Comment: @PranavPillai Oh, I see, yeah, that's problematic. The other trick I use is to cache a copy of the state in a React ref that is updated via a `useEffect` hook when the state updates. Access the ref's current value in your callback. I'll add an example.